# How to disable a particular cell in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor, defaulttablemodel

I am working with swing. I Have a `JTable` having 8 columns and Dynamic rows.
2nd column is non-editable which I did like this in `DefaultTableModel`.

```
static JComboBox combo1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox(new String[]{"Static","Project Variable", "External", "Output Variable"});
            ParametersTable.setModel(new     javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            parametersTableData,
            new String[]{
                "S.No", "Parameters", "Parameter Type", "Static Value", "Variable Name", "Sheet Name", "Column Name", "Output Variable"
            }
            ) { 
Class[] types = new Class[]{
                    java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class
                };

                public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                    return types[columnIndex];
                }

                boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[]{
                    true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true 
                };

                public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                    return canEdit[columnIndex];
                }
            }       
            );
            ParametersTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(combo1));
```

I have a `JComboBox` in 3rd column which has values `static,project variable,external,output variable`.

Assuming there are 2 Rows ,So when I select Parameter Type as `static` in first row, i want that particular `cell` (Static Value) to be enabled in that particular row and rest of the cells to be disabled.
Similarly when I select Parameter Type as "Output Variable" in second row. I want that particular cell (Output Variable) to be enabled in that particular row and rest of the cells to be disabled.

Comment: Base you decision for enabling/disabling the cells not on the array, but the value of the 3rd column...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Is there any way to achieve this functionality. Can we disable a particular CELL in swings ? If so , Please guide me which helps a lot..

Comment: Yes, use the model's `getVaueAt` method to get the value for 3rd column for the given row and return a `boolean` based on your rules for `isCelLEditable`

Answer (score 4):

Change your `isCellEditable` as follows.

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    String comboValue = ParametersTable.getValueAt(rowIndex, 0).toString(); //0 is the column index where your combo box value available.
    if(comboValue.equals("static")){
        return false; //The cell (row, column) will be non editable
    }
    return canEdit[columnIndex];
}
```